# How to use Identity UserManager in multi-project solutions in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, clean-architecture

I'm new at ASP.NET Core.

I have an service class named `IdentityUserService` in the `Infrastructure layer` and this class implements the `IUserService` interface in the `Application layer`.

When I debug the solution, I get the error detailed below. How can i use `UserManager` in the `Infrastructure layer`?

---

**IUserService interface**

```
namespace JobSearch.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.Services;

public interface IUserService
{
    public ICollection<AppUser> GetAllUsers();
}
```

**IdentityUserService**

```
namespace JobSearch.Infrastructure.Services.User;

public class IdentityUserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public IdentityUserService(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        => _userManager = userManager;

    public ICollection<AppUser> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return _userManager.Users.ToList();
    }
}
```

---

**InfrastructureServiceRegistration extension class**

```
namespace JobSearch.Infrastructure;

public static class InfrastructureServiceRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IUserService, IdentityUserService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

> **I called this method in `program.cs`**

---

**UsersController**

```
namespace JobSearch.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public UsersController(IUserService userService)
            => _userService = userService;

        [HttpGet("/[action]", Name = "UsersGetAll")]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Ok(_userService.GetAllUsers());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Exception details**

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2023.1.3\plugins\dpa\DotFiles\JetBrains.DPA.Runner.exe" --handle=16508 --backend-pid=19472 --etw-collect-flags=67108622 --detach-event-name=dpa.detach.16508 C:/Users/ayazz/Projects/JobSearch/src/Presentation/JobSearch.WebAPI/bin/Debug/net8.0/JobSearch.WebAPI.exe
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: JobSearch.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.Services.IUserService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: JobSearch.Infrastructure.Services.User.IdentityUserService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[JobSearch.Domain.Entities.Identity.AppUser]' from singleton 'JobSearch.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.Services.IUserService'.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: JobSearch.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.Services.IUserService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: JobSearch.Infrastructure.Services.User.IdentityUserService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[JobSearch.Domain.Entities.Identity.AppUser]' from singleton 'JobSearch.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.Services.IUserService'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[JobSearch.Domain.Entities.Identity.AppUser]' from singleton 'JobSearch.Application.Contracts.Infrastructure.Services.IUserService'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite scopedCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)        
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\ayazz\Projects\JobSearch\src\Presentation\JobSearch.WebAPI\Program.cs:line 44

Process finished with exit code -532,462,766.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't use a service with a smaller lifetime. Scoped services only exist per-request, while singleton services are created once and the instance is shared. So basically your identity user singleton service is referencing scoped user manager service.

Comment: @SlobodanT Thanks. It solved the problem. It's a pretty simple problem really.

Comment: I am glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is solved.**
**In such a case**, using `AddScoped` instead of `AddSingleton` when adding the IServiceCollection to the IoC fixes the error.

---

**The line causing the error**

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserService, IdentityUserService>();
```

**Fixing the error**

```
services.AddScoped<IUserService, IdentityUserService>();
```